# Problems using Hadoop's DistributedCache

Tags: java, hadoop

Hi I'm having some troubles using Hadoop Distributed cache. I'm running Hadoop in one single node cluster (http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/).

The problem that I need to pass an file to each mapper, I have already read lot of Hadoop's DistributedCache, but until now I had no succes every time I try to open the local file I get a "FileNotFoundException", How I could be sure that the cache is actually coping the file?

Thanks for any help

Here is my code:

```
    package br.ufmg.dcc.bigdata.hadoop;                                        
    import java.io.IOException;                                        
    import java.util.*;                                        
    import org.apache.hadoop.filecache.DistributedCache;                                        
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;                                        
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;                                        
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;                                        
    import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;                                        
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;                                        
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;                                        
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;                                        
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;                                        
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;                                        
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;                                        
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;                                        
    import br.ufmg.dcc.bigdata.Result;                                        
    import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;                                        
    import java.io.BufferedInputStream;                                        
    import java.io.File;                                        
    import java.io.FileInputStream;                                        
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;                                        
    import java.io.FileReader;                                        
    import java.io.InputStream;                                        
    import java.io.ObjectInput;                                        
    import java.io.ObjectInputStream;                                        
    import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;                                        
    import java.io.StringReader;                                        
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;                                        
    import java.io.BufferedReader;                                        
    import java.net.URI;                                        
    import weka.core.Instances;                                        
    import weka.classifiers.rules.LAC;                                        


    public class Ladoop {                                        

        public static class Map extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable> {                                        

            //private                                        
            private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);                                        
            private LAC classifier;                                         
            private Path[] localFiles;                                        
            private final static Text missesText = new Text("misses");                                        
            private final static Text hitsText = new Text("hits");                                        


             protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {                                        


                 FileReader teste = new FileReader("dilma_00.lac"); //error in this line                                        
                 classifier = new LAC("/home/hduser/dilma_00.lac"); //There is no problem if I force to read the local file                                        
             }                                          



            public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {                                        
                String line = value.toString();                                        
                try                                         
                {                                        
                    Result result = this.classifier.distributionForInstance(line.split(" "));                                        
                    context.write(missesText, new IntWritable(result.getMisses()));                                        
                    context.write(hitsText, new IntWritable(result.getHits()));                                        
                } catch (Exception e) {                                        
                    System.out.println("MAP ERROR");                                        
                    e.printStackTrace();                                        
                }                                        
            }                                        

         }                                          


         public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {                                        

             public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> results, Context context)                                         
                     throws IOException, InterruptedException {                                        
                 int    value       = 0;                                        

                 for (IntWritable result : results) {                                        
                     value +=  result.get();                                        
                 }                                        
                 System.out.println(value);                                        
                 context.write(key, new IntWritable(value));                                        

             }                                        
         }                                        

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {                                        
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();                                        

            Job job = new Job(conf, "Ladoop");                                        
            DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI("/user/hduser/dilma_00.lac#dilma_00.lac"), conf);    




            DistributedCache.createSymlink(conf);                                        


            job.setJarByClass(Ladoop.class);                                        

            job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);                                        
            job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);                                        

            job.setMapperClass(Map.class);                                        
            job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);                                        

            job.setInputFormatClass(NonSplittableKeyValueTextInputFormat.class);                                        
            job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);                                        

            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));                                        
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));                                        

            job.waitForCompletion(true);                                        
        }                                        

    }
```

Edit: Tried also with, but had no luck.

```
     protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
         Path[] cacheFiles = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(context.getConfiguration());
         FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(cacheFiles[0].toString());
         classifier = new LAC(cacheFiles[0].toString());
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access files directly after putting them in your `DistributedCache`, you should add something like this in your `setup` code:

```
Path[] cacheFiles = context.getLocalCacheFiles();
FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(cacheFiles[0].toString());
```

Comment: Had no luck with that also, edited my question with the code used.

Answer (score 0):

If you Have Hadoop 2.1.0-beta, it has a bug in setting and getting from cache try another version, http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-5385